# Does an action that Messenger of Allah did in private count as Sunnah?

Tags: sunnah, terminology

The Messenger of Allah (P.B.U.H) did things in private, some of which may have been narrated by his wives.

By private, I mean within boundaries of his home.

Do these count as Sunnah ?

Comment: This is relevant [What is the the khabar how is it different than sira Akbar sunnah hadith in general?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/36568/what-is-the-khabar-how-is-it-different-than-sira-akbar-sunnah-hadith-in-ge).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it does. This is based on the following ayah:

> وَاذْكُرْنَ مَا يُتْلَىٰ فِي بُيُوتِكُنَّ مِنْ آيَاتِ اللَّهِ وَالْحِكْمَةِ ۚ إِنَّ اللَّهَ كَانَ لَطِيفًا خَبِيرًا
>
> [O Wives of the Prophet] Remember what is recited in **your houses** of God’s revelations and **wisdom**, for God is all subtle, all aware.
>
> -Sura Al-Ahzab, Ayah 34

As this Ayah shows, the wives were commanded to remember (and by extension tell people) the wisdom which is the hadith and actions of the Prophet (SAW) even what he did in his house.

Answer (score 3):

The Scholars of Hadith define sunnah as,

> Anything narrated from or about the Prophet  sallallaahu  `alayhi  wa
>   sallam ( may  Allah exalt his mention ) either before or after he
>   became a prophet, of his statements, actions, confirmations,
>   biography, and his physical character and attributes.

Source: http://www.islamweb.net/en/article/174849/the-sunnah-of-the-prophet-definitions

This includes all actions and sayings both private and public.

The private life of the Prophet sallallaahu  `alayhi  wa  sallam has a lot of guidance for us, just like his public life.